# How to use a petrol/gas station in Greece?

Tags: greece, gas-stations

I'm going to be using a rental car in an upcoming holiday to Greece. At some point I will need to refuel the car. I've heard that most petrol stations in Greece are manned by an attendant who will fill your vehicle for you. I've only ever used self-service petrol stations in my life so would like to know what the typical process of using a manned petrol station is in Greece. Here are some of the specific questions I have, but please cover anything else you think would be useful:

- Do you pay before or after the attendant pumps?
- If you pay before the attendant pumps, how can you ask for the tank to be filled to full?
- Do attendants expect tips?

Comment: I just came back from Greece and did this. You pull up, tell them "full" and they'll fill it full. You do not tip, and you can even pay with Apple Pay without having to touch the machine. Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pay after the attendant pumps, and no tips. Some attendants may recommend more expensive gas.  Some stations aren't 24/7.